# Symfony getData() return null value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I am new in `Symfony`, i had existing `Document` as `User.php`, Here is my old file.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
       return $this->name;
    }

}
```

Then i need to add new filed email, then i changed `User.php`, here is updated file.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

    class User extends BaseUser
    {
        /**
         * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
        */
       protected $email;

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
           return $this->name;
        }

        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getEmail()
        {
           return $this->email;
        }

    }
```

Then i tried to get value of email its show `null`, I cheeked my database and there is value is exist in email field. Here is my code.

```
$user = $this->dm()->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);
var_dump($user->getEmail());
```

i also removed all cache using following commands.

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

also remove cache using `rm -rf var/cache` but its still give null value.
whats wrong with me? can you help me?

Comment: There's no email property defined with annotation.

Comment: Opps! i forgot to add in here. I updated my question.

Comment: Try to dump $user ?

Comment: @JulesR, Yes, i checked  there is also null value for email.

Comment: But did you set it before ?

Comment: i didn't set value but email value exist in User document,when i execute find query  is it set automatically? or we need to set manually?

Comment: I mean, you're fetching User from database, but is email set in the database ?

Comment: Yes, email is exist there.

Comment: I added manually in database

Comment: Are you sur your property name in db in exactly `email` ? as you added it manually there could have an error here. Could you add your document in DB in your question ? (the json representing the Document).

Comment: @Etshy, Yes its email, i checked again.

Answer (score 0):

Email is already defined in Baseuser. Maybe you have To add 
parent::getEmail() or remove the getter totally

Comment: Thanks, i checked BaseUser.php and there is no any Getter or Setter method for email.

Comment: FOSUserbundle has got it included.


Therefore the Getter must be

public function getEmail()
{
$this->email = parent::getEmail();
return $this->email;
}